# Python relative imports. "Attempted relative import beyond top-level package"

Tags: python

I would like to have a file with constants in my project's root directory. I'm trying to solve this my using relative imports. What I've tried so far is:

I have the following structure

```
└── project
    ├── packageA
    │   ├── fileA.py # contains class A
    │
    └── definitions.py
    └── main.py
```

## Contents of fileA.py

```
from ..definitions import hello_world

class A:
    def __init__(self):
        print(hello_world)
```

## Contents of definitions.py

```
hello_world = "Hello world"
```

## Contents of main.py

```
from packageA.fileA import A

A()
```

I'm standing in the project dir and running the command

```
python3 main.py
```

I get the following error

```
 line 1, in <module>
    from ..definitions import hello_world
ValueError: attempted relative import beyond top-level package
```

So what am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
from ..definations import hello_world
```

You can just use

```
from definations import hello_world
```